# itextpdf embeding fonts only from command line

Tags: php, linux, fonts, embed, itextpdf

I use itextpdf on Ubuntu to fill in a PDF form with data. In fact i use a class (utility) included in this kit: PdfFormFiller. The data is represented by Unicode strings. To display correctly the Unicode characters I use -fonts option of PdfFormFiller.

For this I wrote a PHP script that simply calls PdfFormFiller with correct parameters.

```
<?php
$command = "java -cp ./bin:lib/itextpdf-5.5.3.jar PdfFormFiller.PdfFormFiller DIPLOMA_FORM.pdf -f test.fdf -font \"fonts/arial.ttf\" -flatten test.pdf";
exec($command);
?>
```

When I run the PHP file as root from command line (php ) everything is fine. The PDF has the font embeded and characters are displayed correctly.

But when I run the script from web (access the link) the generated PDF does not include the needed font (Arial with all Unicode characters).

I tried to refer the font file (in PHP script) with absolute path, relative (to web page) path and variations. No go.

I allowed apache user all access rights to all files involved. No go.

Any ideas?

Comment: what makes you think `php` running from  your root account has the same permissions as `php` running as web service?

Comment: I set "apache" as owner and group for all the files involved and permission to everything (rwx).

Comment: Please share your PHP script.

Comment: <?php                                                                                                                                                                
$command = "java -cp ./bin:lib/itextpdf-5.5.3.jar PdfFormFiller.PdfFormFiller DIPLOMA_FORM.pdf -f test.fdf -font \"fonts/arial.ttf\" -flatten test.pdf";             
exec($command);                                                                                                                                                      
?>

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I solved the problem using FPDF. Works like a charm with UTF-8.

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php

L.E. tfpdf is even better. :)

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php